# Many attempted access to /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document in logs? Security issue?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, security

I am running a PHP app on AWS EC2. The server crashed with thousands of these in the logs:
ErrorGET /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document

I get that this describes the instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html

But is this AWS doing something, or someone trying to mess with the server?

Thanks,

Comment: The first thing you can do is check the webserver logs for repetitive access by any specific ip. requesting the instance identify document can be a security breach.  AWS WAF can help you block ip's if you find one which is problematic

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ali. Looking in the access logs now seems very obvious :), and was helpful

Answer (score 3):

This is security assessment service for applications deployed on Amazon EC2.

> Amazon Inspector is an automated security assessment service that helps improve the security and compliance of applications deployed on AWS. Amazon Inspector automatically assesses applications for exposure, vulnerabilities, and deviations from best practices. After performing an assessment, Amazon Inspector produces a detailed list of security findings prioritized by level of severity. These findings can be reviewed directly or as part of detailed assessment reports which are available via the Amazon Inspector console or API.

-- [AWS Inspector](https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/)

Context: Even i had multiple access logs from Amazon's ip. I checked headers for these access logs.

```
{
    "host": "[IP_Address]",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "user-agent": "AWS Security Scanner",
    "content-length": "",
    "content-type": ""
}
```